# The default settings RGB background are in Blender

Tags: rendering, image, color

I am rendering the image with Blender. The rendered images are saved as black and white images. I am wondering what **the default settings RGB background** are in Blender because I need to make the renderings consistent between Blender and the software that I use to present. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome Thomas! What other application? Eevee or Cycles? Do you mean the *World Background* (default grey)? Why you can't just set it to transparent?

Comment: (0.051, 0.051, 0.051) in scene linear is the default value for the world background. Is that what you mean?